# What is the difference between character classes \d and [:digit:] in a regular expression?

Tags: regular-expression

I studied a [tutorial for vim syntax](https://vim.fandom.com/wiki/Creating_your_own_syntax_files) files and found this example:

```
" Floating point like number with E and no decimal point (+,-)
syn match celNumber '[-+]\=\d[[:digit:]]*[eE][\-+]\=\d\+'
```

I was surprised that it uses both `\d` *and* `[:digit:]`. I thought they mean the same thing. The vim help for `pattern` says:

```
Character classes:
      magic   nomagic   matches ~
...
\d    \d      \d        digit:    [0-9]
```

And for `[:...:]` character classes:

```
- A character class expression is evaluated to the set of characters
  belonging to that character class.  The following character classes
  are supported:
Name          Func         Contents ~
...
[:digit:]     [:digit:]    decimal digits '0' to '9'
```

So what is the difference? Can't the example pattern `\d[[:digit:]]*` be simplified to `\d\+`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is no difference in which symbols they encompass; both denote the digits from 0 to 9. They only differ in where they *can* resp. *must* be used. `\d` can not be used inside a collection, i.e., `/[\d]/` will search for backslashes and lower case Ds, but not for digits. In contrast to this, `[:digit:]` must be used *inside* a collection, i.e., only `/[[:digit:]]/` will search for a digit -- `/[:digit:]/` would search for one of the letters d, g, i, t or for a colon.

And yes, `\d[[:digit:]]*` can be simplified to `\d\+`.